# Is there a way to call a bootstraptour function within a button or link?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I would like to call a bootstraptour function when a user clicks on a button or link with the id of "#tip-back-btn-1"

Is there a way where I can just call the bootstraptour goto function directly in a button or link?

I would like to use something like this:

```
<button class="tip-skip-button" id="tip-back-btn-1" onclick="tour.goTo(0);">Back</button>
```

I tried calling

```
$("#tip-back-btn-1").click(function() {
    tour.goTo(0);
});
```

But this doesn't work

My bootstraptour code is below for reference

```
    'use strict';

        $(function () {
            var steps = [];
            var leadIndex = 0;
            function gensteps(index, div, message, placement, template) {

                var id = $(div).attr('id');

                if (id === undefined) {
                    //$(body).attr('id', 'id_' + leadIndex + '_' + index);
                    id = $(div).attr('id');
                }
                var step = {
                    element: '#' + id,
                    content: message,
                    placement: placement,
                    template: template,
                    backdropElement: '#client-activated-update-client-info'
                };
                steps.push(step);
            }


            leadIndex++;
            $('#contain').each(function (index, div) {
                var template = '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"> <div class="arrow"></div> <div class="popover-content"></div> <div class="popover-navigation"> <div class="btn-group-custom"> <button class="tip-skip-button" id="tip-back-btn-1">Back</button> </div> <button class="tip-exit" data-role="end">Exit</button> </div> </div>';
                gensteps(index, div, '<h3 class="tool-tip-title">Address</h3>\n    <div class="tip-content">\n    <p>lorem ipsum dolet</p>\n </div>\n ', 'top',template);
            });


            $("#tip-back-btn-1").click(function() {
                tour.goTo(1);
            });



            var tour = new Tour({
                steps: steps
            });tour.init();
            tour.start(true);
            tour.goTo(0);


    });
```

I think the problem is that my tool tip button code is defined too early and the DOM element having the ID "button" does not exists yet. Or maybe all of my tour code hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Try replacing `$("#tip-back-btn-1").click(function()` with `$("document").on("click", "#tip-back-btn-1", function()`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that method before but what if I would like to use multiple Ids and call multiple functions.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking; this change simply makes use of event delegation. Does it fix the problem? And you can always just have two lines, like `$("document").on("click", "#tip-back-btn-1", function1() ...` and `$("document").on("click", "#tip-back-btn-1", function2() ...`. Don't forget you can always use class selectors or pass the target element into the function itself :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I was not aware that you could use $("document").on multiple times in a document.

Comment: @ObsidianAge  Actually Your suggestion does work for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try defining it out of function

```
var tour = new Tour();
    $(function () {
tour = new Tour({
                steps: steps
            });tour.init();
            tour.start(true);
            tour.goTo(0);
}
```

hopefully solves your problem